# What causes shiny artifacts in Google Maps imagery?

Tags: google-maps, imagery

Do you know what causes artifacts like this one?

[image]

Source: http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&source=s_q&hl=en&geocode=&q=embelgasse+wien&aq=&sll=37.0625,-95.677068&sspn=60.894251,93.251953&ie=UTF8&hq=&hnear=Embelgasse,+Margareten+1050+Wien,+Austria&t=h&ll=48.187123,16.348997&spn=0.001849,0.004667&z=18

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps it is glass roofs and the angle of the sun at the time of the capture.

Bing Maps [Satellite] is okay
http://www.bing.com/maps/?v=2&where1=48.187141%2C%2016.349561&q=48.187141%2C16.349561&cp=48.18694871145921~16.349901334904583&lvl=18&encType=1

Comment: It does sort of look like a lens flare. Weird that it would "eat" the image though; it's almost as if part of it was physically cut out.

Comment: I also thought of lens flare, especially because of the white diagonal. But I'm not sure that explains the totally white area on the lower side.

Comment: Looks photoshoped for reason though what that reason is unknown. If the ortho-rectification was done in stereo the glare might have been block out on purpose http://photogrammetrydevelopment.blogspot.com/2011/01/3d-photogrammetry-tutorial-about.html

Comment: The stars are not lens flare: they are likely Fraunhofer diffraction. See http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/6605/1356 .  That they occur at six angles suggests a hexagonal camera diaphragm; that some occur in parallel rows suggests multiple (three?) bright lights are involved. That they are white rules out a laser; this has to be a direct solar reflection from good mirrors. The directions of the shadows and of the buildings suggests the sun is almost directly behind the sensor: the mirrors point right at us (and the sun). But the presence of the empty patch and the rainbow patch are a mystery.

Comment: @whuber rainbow could be due to motion of sensor while capturing different wavelengths. See link on OP by @capdragon.

Comment: @mankoff Interesting idea.  Initially it seems the sensor motion would show as a uniformly displaced "rainbow", whereas these patches exhibit no such pattern.  Also, the phenomenon is not associated with sensor motion, but with *object* motion relative to the ground.  Perhaps the sensor's motion created an *apparent,* complex motion of the sun's reflection off a bright ground-based object that is not perfectly flat.

Comment: Another thought: the apparent solar reflection in the OP would likely have affected only one-half of a stereo pair.  The extreme mis-match in the two sides would have really screwed up the orthorectification algorithm.  That might explain the missing patch.

Comment: @whuber you are right it is object motion, otherwise **everything** would be rainbow'd. Duh. :).

Answer (score 1):

I think many of these artifacts might be caused by solar energy collection mechanisms. Even photovoltaic cells reflect some sunlight. I say that because I've noticed that when one of these artifacts is present it's likely there's more in the vicinity.

Take a look at the city Gaziantep in Google Maps.

You'll notice there's a high clustering of these artifacts there. This suggests that there's a regularity to their positioning, and what reflective surface do you know of that follows the angle of the sun?

Answer (score 0):

I found this while looking at my grandparents house on Google maps, similar to the one in this post. It's a small storage house and I think it has a metal roof, although the barn has a metal roof and didn't look the same. .[image]

Answer (score 0):

A mirror (or highly reflective surface) reflecting sunlight directly back into the lens. Like we used to do in school when we would deflect a beam, of sunlight into another kids eye in class to distract them. That is the prisming effect you see. This is the most likely culprit.

[image]